# Magento 2 add new website in existing website steps

Tags: multi-website, magento2.4.0

I have a existing website for Canada and all products attributes at global and if I add new website for USA and follow all steps successfully to add new website so then should I update all products and categories for USA store also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Create the Website for USA
- Then travel to Admin - Catalog -> Products, there select all the products and then in the action dropdown, select - update attributes, you will find Website, assign those products to that USA website as well.
- And last step run cron with the below command

  php bin/magento cron:run

Thanks,